# AttributeError: type object 'class' has no attribute 'method'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Keep getting the error, `AttributeError: type object 'SampleApp' has no attribute 'draw'`. I looked at other resources for this question and seen none where the method was trying to be called from another class. I have also tried `def draw()` inside and outside the `_init_`. 
The purpose of this is that on class B there will be input for the user, and when the button is hit widgets will be drawn to the frame on the Sample App, but so far I can't do that.

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):


    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self, width=426, height=600)
        self.left_frame.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=3, rowspan=10)

        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self, width=855, borderwidth=2, 
        relief="solid")
        self.right_frame.grid(column=4, row=0, rowspan=9, sticky="nsew")


        self.frames = {}
        for F in (A, B):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=self.left_frame, controller=self)
            frame.configure(width=426, height=511, borderwidth=2, 
            relief="solid")
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, 
            rowspan=2,sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("A")


        def draw():
            print("We")
            label = tk.Label(self.left_frame_bottom, text="Hello")
            label.pack()


class A(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("B"))
        button.pack()

 class B(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
         self.controller = controller


         submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", 
         command=lambda:SampleApp.draw())
         submit_button.place(x=180, y=320)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Check the indentation of `def draw()`

Comment: If I move the def draw() out of the scope of _init_, I am unable to get access to the frame. The error I get is NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

Comment: See below.  You need to pass self to the method.

Comment: It should also be `def draw(self):`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix the indentation of `draw` - it's indented one level too much. `def draw` needs to be indented the same as `def show_frame`.

Second, since `draw` is a method on the controller, you need to call it via the controller instance:

```
self.controller.draw()
```

Answer (score -1):

Outdent your `draw()` function so that it is at the same level as `__init__()`.  Make sure you pass self `def draw(self):` and if you need it to run when you create an instance, then just call `self.draw()` in your `__init__()` definition.

Comment: I don't understand where the self.draw() is to go within _init_?

Comment: This answer won't work. You can only use `self.draw` inside a method of `SampleApp`, but the OP wants to call it from the other classes.